# Connection Error: Excel VBA to Remote MySQL

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, odbc

I have two work computers, on same network, same public ip.  I'm able to connect successfully to my mySQL database from localhost on the computer 1.  I'm trying to connect to the same database from computer 2 via Excel VBA.  I've tried

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* to user@'ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'
```

**Excel VBA:**

```
Dim strServer As String
Dim strDBName As String
Dim strUserID As String
Dim strPasswd As String

strServer = "ipaddress"
strDBName = "dbname"
strUserID = "userid"
strPasswd = "pass"

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
  With oConn
    .ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};" & _
          "Server=" & strServer & ";Port=3306;" & _
          "Database=" & strDBName & ";" & _
          "Uid=" & strUserID & ";" & _
          "Pwd=" & strPasswd & ";Option=3;"
     .Open
End With

MsgBox "Connection Successful"
```

**Excel VBA Error:**

> "Run-time error '-2147467259 (800004005)': [MySQL][ODBC 5.2(w)
>   Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip' (10061)"

Is my syntax off somewhere, or am I missing something?  (I also have 3 other work computers, on different networks, that I would like to grant similar privileges to, as they're all using a shared Excel workbook).

Comment: Hi buddy, I'm facing exactly the same issue, did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* 'user'@'ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'` will do the trick for you.  User name is in quotes, too, as per [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html).

Comment: tried it, still receiving same Excel VBA Exception Message

Comment: What happens when you test the connection in ODBC setup?